# app's language in app store is wrong

Tags: ios, app-store

I uploaded an app whose language is Chinese to the app store, and I set the default language to Simplified Chinese in iTunes Connect. But in the app store, the language item is English. I don't know why. How do I fix this? App store [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ge-lin-kang-quan-fu/id643531205?ls=1&mt=8).

[image: iTunes Connect]

Comment: This is a link to US App Store.

Comment: @rokjarc Yes,but the language item should be Chinese.There is only one  language in this app

Comment: I see (and of course it shows the same in China App Store). Your settings seem correct. Is your app properly localized?

Comment: @rokjarc I just use default configuration.

Comment: seems like the AppStore use the *.lproj folders in your app to decide what are the available languages. Maybe if it doesn't find one it use the default developer language present in you info.plist file

Comment: Jerome Diaz is right. It's not enough to simply select the language in iTunes Connect. You have to localize your app for that language. This would be a good start: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interfacing with Apple's App Store, not programming. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 3):

Change localizations strings and submit app again

[image]

[image]